# How to make complete eval result as a return value of function

Tags: php, function, eval

I know, eval is called 'evil' and it's seems to be the worst way for everything, but...
How to return complete result of eval outside of function? It is just hypotetic question, I've found easy better solution for me.

In database (want execute):

```
$var1 = "yes";
$var2 = "no";
include('file.php');
```

---

function:

```
function executeScriptData($id) {
     $data = anydbhandler("SELECT `data` FROM `data` WHERE ID = $id");
     if(trim($data['data']) != "") {
          echo $data['data']; // echo data from database
          return eval($data['data']);
     }
}
```

---

calling function:

```
executeScriptData(someID);
```

---

```
echo $var1; // nothing happened :(, no result
```

Comment: Not possible. $var1/$var2 will be LOCAL variables defined only in the scope of the `executeScriptData` function. Once the function returns, they'll be destroyed. You'd have to explicitly return an array of all new variables, or use globals.

Comment: OK, if it's the final answer. I will accept, there is something impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the evalling happens in the scope you want it to (now `$var1` is only available within the method `executeScriptData()`).

Possible solution:

```
function executeScriptData($id) {
    $data = dbhandler("SELECT `data` FROM `data` WHERE ID = $id");
    if(trim($data['data']) != "") {
        return $data['data'];
    }
}

$data = executeScriptData(SOMEID);
eval($data);

echo $var1;
```

Comment: where you use `$id`? fix the query please. This case that is a string.

Comment: @lolka_bolka It looks like pseudocode... And that's beside the point... The scope is the problem and not the $id... Second of all... without seeing the implementation of `dbhandler()` this could very well be perfect code ;)

Comment: Yes, this is my 'easy and better' solution (I've got function getScriptData() which returns that string and than eval that), but is possible to make it like in my question? I try something with `ob_start() eval($data['data']); $return = ob_end_flush(); return $return` but no effect again.

Comment: ob catches OUTPUT. `$var = 'foo'` is NOT output. it's just creating a variable. you'd need to `echo $var` for ob to catch something. and even then, it wouldn't be the variable itself, only its CONTENTS.

Comment: @RadimKleinpeter it is not possible to return the eval... Scoping prevents that (which is a good thing). You will have to use my solution to have these variables there. Like MarB said, it is not possible to retrieve these variables with `ob_`-functions

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible via return value as the docs are telling you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Returnvalues:

eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned. If there is a parse error in the evaluated code, eval() returns FALSE and execution of the following code continues normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in eval() using set_error_handler().

---

The return you are using there is in a subscope of eval, in an extra function. This scope cannot make your evaluation end. Otherwise eval() would not be able to define functions within its contents because every occurence of "return" would screw the code execution passed to eval().

All you can do is make a var global within your eval'ed code and overwrite it in context.

```
$a = true;
$myVar = "abc";

eval('global $a; global $myVar; if($a == true) { $myVar = "def"; } ');

echo $myVar;
```